# Querying WFS with bounding box and also clip the returning feature coordinates to be within the bbox

Tags: wfs

Looking at the following request

```
https://ows.emodnet-humanactivities.eu/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&OUTPUTFORMAT=json&srsName=EPSG:4326&typeName=emodnet:maritimebnds&bbox=1.449667700940239,58.43688912376908,2.333258719167958,59.31172287557638,EPSG:4326
```

I am able to clip the result to only contain features that land inside the bounding box. HOWEVER, the feature itself is a huge `MultiLineString` that have coordinates WAAY outside the bounding box. Is it possible to query the WFS in such a way that it will clip the feature itself?

The following images shows the result, where the green line is the returned feature, the points are the bbox lower left and upper right
[image: The green line is the returned feature, the points are the bbox lower left and upper right]

By selecting the feature we see that it is one huge feature!
[image: By selecting the feature we see that it is one huge feature!]

Note I have also tried to use a filter using the filter function available in WFS

```
<wfs:GetFeature
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
service="WFS"
version="1.1.0"
outputFormat="json"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <wfs:Query typeName="emodnet:maritimebnds" srsName="EPSG:4326">
    <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <ogc:BBOX>
        <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
        <gml:Envelope xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326">
          <gml:lowerCorner>1.449667700940239 58.43688912376908</gml:lowerCorner>
          <gml:upperCorner>2.333258719167958 59.31172287557638</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
      </ogc:BBOX>
    </ogc:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

but it gives similar results.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `BBOX` filter which is the same as `INTERSECTS` the bbox, you should look for features who's geometries are `CONTAIN`ed by the bbox polygon. So something like:

```
<wfs:GetFeature
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
service="WFS"
version="1.1.0"
outputFormat="json"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <wfs:Query typeName="emodnet:maritimebnds" srsName="EPSG:4326">
    <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <ogc:Contains>
        <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
        <gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326">
          <gml:ExteriorRing>
             <gml:PosList>.....
          </gml:ExteriorRing>
         </gml:Polygon>
      </ogc:Contains>
    </ogc:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I don't think that is correct either. The feature as you can see in the picture is not CONTAINED by the bounding box, it is in fact going much further outside. If I filter by CONTAINED I get no feature back. What I want is to FIRST filter with a bbox and then CLIP the returned feature

Comment: Then you either need to clip it in the client or look to see if a WPS service is available to clip it for you. There's nothing in the WFS spec to help you out.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense